# Fitting a Pareto distribution to two dimensional data in R

Tags: r, power-law

I've looked here:
[How do I fit a set of data to a Pareto distribution in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27426/how-)
do-i-fit-a-set-of-data-to-a-pareto-distribution-in-r

and I've checked out the poweRlaw library which is built for fitting data to power distributions.

But all of these solutions focus on fitting data which is a single vector.  I have data which is two-dimensional,  A data frame that consists of two vectors of the same size and they are both power distributions.

Here is the printout of the data frame softwareDevMarket:

```
   revenue companyCount   
1      0.5        14908  
2      1.0         3743  
3      2.5         3055  
4      5.0         1359  
5     10.0          760  
6     25.0          398  
7     50.0           80  
8    100.0           44  
9    250.0           39  
10   500.0           15  
11  1000.0           12
```

Here is my attempt:

```
library("poweRlaw")
m <- conpl$new(softwareDevMarket);   # conpl means continuous powerlaw.
```

At this point, I get an error because the "new" function doesn't accept data frames as an argument.  I am fairly new to R, so I suspect that
I am missing something fairly obvious here.  I just need a good estimation of the distributions parameters so that I can find the average and standard deviation of it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the second distribution?  Your example provides only one distribution (by showing counts within varying ranges of numbers).

Comment: I might be mixed up here.    Maybe this is a 1D distribution?   I thought the counts were their own distribution.

Comment: These data describe 24,413 numbers by putting them into the bins $[0,0.5], (0.5,1],\ldots,(500,1000]$ and counting how many numbers fall into each bin.  That is a *frequency distribution* of those numbers.  The bin *cutpoints* (the `revenue` field) aren't a distribution--they simply describe the boundaries between successive bins.

Comment: I ended up making a linear model by taking the log of each column using lm(log(revenue) ~ log(companyCount)),  Then I calculated the log average of that line and used that.  I ended up with the expected revenue of 0.275 million.  I am sure I am making an error somewhere here, I read somewhere that doing a log transform introduces a bias, and that a max likelihood estimator is better to use.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that when the power of the Pareto distribution is $\alpha=1$ or less, it has no mean; and when the power is $2$ or less, it has no standard deviation. The Maximum Likelihood estimate for your data is $\hat\alpha=0.83$: your data are consistent with a distribution that has no mean or SD.  (It's not a perfect fit, though: the mid-level counts are a bit too high and the higher counts a bit too low.)  Are you sure you want to estimate the mean and SD *of a Pareto distribution,* or do you really want to find the mean and SD *of the data?*

Comment: I am assuming that to find the SD and mean I should use the appropriate model.  It's not a normal distribution, so using the average and SD of the data under that assumption would give an incorrect result, (because the outliers would skew the mean).  What do you mean by find the mean and SD of the data,  (these stats depend on the model used).

Comment: The information you posted summarizes 24,413 numbers. If you fit a Pareto distribution to them, then (1) it has no mean or SD but (2) it's not a perfect fit. The reason it has no mean or SD is that it projects substantial probability that much larger numbers exist which have not yet appeared in your sample. The accuracy of that projection is doubtful, due to (2). What you haven't clearly indicated is whether you (a) want to compute the mean and SD of those 24,413 numbers only or (b) want to estimate the mean of some "true" underlying distribution. Which is it?

Comment: I want to estimate the mean and standard deviation of the true underlying distribution.  The purpose of this is to make a decision whether starting a business is a good choice in comparison to working for someone else even when uncertainty exists in starting a business.  I am making this choice under the assumption that I am going to build an average software company with average revenue.

I am assuming my behaviour towards risk is Risk Neutral in this case, so the expected value is really all that matters.

Comment: A Pareto model is inappropriate for this purpose because it projects an infinite mean.  You can obtain a more than good enough estimate of the expectation simply by using the mean of the data.

Comment: If you run the code provided in the next post on the data you will get alpha = 2.25703 and xmin = 0.5.  Since alpha > 2 the mean and variance are defined. Where are you getting alpha < 1 from?   If I simply calculated the mean and standard deviation of the data I would get mean = 3.31 and sd = 27.86 which does not make sense because that would mean that almost half of all software companies have negative revenue.  Unless that is somewhat true?

Answer (score 6):

You need to expand you data frame to generate the raw data (silly I know, on my list of things to fix)

```
## Dummy data
softwareDevMarket = data.frame(revenue=1:4, 
                               companyCount = c(1, 3, 5, 10))

## Expand out
x = rep(softwareDevMarket$revenue, softwareDevMarket$companyCount)
## Create a poweRlaw object
m = poweRlaw::conpl$new(x)
```

Once you have a poweRlaw object, you can estimate the associated parameters (alpha, xmin) via

```
estimate_xmin(m)
```

See [section 2.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/d_jss_paper.pdf) of the package vignette for the formulas for the moments of the density.

Comment: This is a useful comment--but it doesn't appear to answer the underlying question.  Once the software issues are worked out, the OP is still left needing to estimate the mean and variance of the underlying distribution.  Would you be able to expand this post to address that issue, too?

Comment: @whuber I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you.  I will use this solution in my next risk assessment update, and will check mark it then.  :)

Comment: @csgillespie I was wondering the same thing about the data you use in your examples in the packages [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/b_powerlaw_examples.pdf), why don't you expand out `moby`, `swiss_prot` etc. ? They seem to be collapsed datasets representing counts? It makes a big difference to plots etc....I thought I should be using raw data? Thanks

Comment: Do `sort(moby)`

Comment: sorry, I dont get you, that data would already be sorted? What I was thinking is `df <- data.frame(moby_long = moby, x = 1:length(moby)) %>% tidyr::uncount(moby_long)` and then create `poweRlaw` object on that data, the raw data, using `m_long = displ$new(df$x)`. The resulting plots of the cdfs are very different.