# Fitting data to a Pareto with small alpha

Tags: r, pareto-distribution

I have a few data points (12) that look like a pareto distribution. When I try to find the MLE parameters in R, (using [How do I fit a set of data to a Pareto distribution in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27426/how-do-i-fit-a-set-of-data-to-a-pareto-distribution-in-r)), the parameter $\alpha$ comes out as 0.008 or so. Then, to verify that those parameters are correct, I want to generate a few pareto distributions with these parameters, but when I type:

```
rpareto(x,xm,alpha)
```

I get an error saying `s must be >1`

The package for `rpareto` is `rmutil`

Is there a different way to estimate $\alpha$ with a small sample? or to generate data with a small $\alpha$?

Comment: maybe  $rpareto()$ use a different parameterization than is used for the MLE-estimation. Pls. state from which package the function is otherwise it is difficult to answer.

Comment: From rmutil. I edited my question to reflect this.